# What is the meaning of double underscore in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a PHP function from the Internet like this:

```
function Del_Inflection_Suffixes($kata) {
    $kataAsal = $kata;
    if(preg_match('/([km]u|nya|[kl]ah|pun)$/', $kata)) { // Cek Inflection Suffixes
        $__kata = preg_match_replace('/([km]u|nya|[kl]ah|pun)$/', '', $kata);
        if(preg_match('([klt]ah|pun)$', $kata)) { // Jika berupa particles (“-lah”,     “-kah”, “-tah” atau “-pun”)
            if(preg_match('/([km]u|nya)$/', $__kata)) { // Hapus Possesive Pronouns (“-ku”, “-mu”, atau “-nya”)
                $__kata__ = preg_match_replace('/([km]u|nya)$/', '', $__kata);
                return $__kata__;
            }
        }
        return $__kata;
    }
    return $kataAsal;
}
```

What is the meaning of **$___kata** and **$_**kata****?

Is that the same as **$kata** on the top of function?

Comment: there is no special meaning of it just user defined variables.

Comment: I'm almost sure that it is just a variable and it doesn't have any special meaning.

Comment: *NOTE* Yes They don't have any special meaning but It mostly using in the PHP Magic functions

Comment: Like the others have said, there is no special meaning. But in PHP there are functions and a few variables that start with underscores, such as __construct. Personally I use underscores at the start when I want to make sure I don't touch that variable by mistake since it's needed by another function.

Comment: looks like it's just a recommendation to differentiate between types of functions / variables, have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554835/functions-and-variables-beginning-with-a-single-or-double-underscore)

Comment: woww very fast answer :D

thanks all for the fast response and the answers..very helpful for me..now i can understand what the meaning of..

Comment: Related (not a duplicate, despite the title): *[Double underscore in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777131/double-underscore-in-php/1777147#1777147)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are different variables. They aren't related in any special way. `$foo`, `$__foo__` and `$__foo` are all simply different variables like `$a, $b, $c`.

Answer (score 4):

Some coders use underscore to identify some types of variables: $__constant, $simplevariable.

Other than that, it means nothing in PHP as it is not a pre-defined function. However, in many frameworks, like [CakePHP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CakePHP), and other libraries, the double underscore is a function used for translating strings based on the user's language/locale preference.

Comment: The last part is also covered in *[Double underscore in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777131/double-underscore-in-php/1777147#1777147)*.